# sharepoint unique columns and empty values

Tags: sharepoint-2010, unique-constraint

So I have this problem with columns in a sharepoint site that's really frustrating me. I need a lookup column to be unique but only when a value is chosen. In other words, it must not have duplicating values but can have more than one (None) values.

I tied this on my test site and it worked like a charm. Just as I expected. I can choose values from the looked up list or leave the column (None), but when I try choosing existing value, an error is fired in the list form.

However when I tied the same thing on my production site the behavior was that I could not have more than one (None) value in the column.

I'm fairly new to sharepoint, so it may be sothing i missed. I could not find helpful information about this in the web and I'm wondering what is the default behavior for the unique constraint? Is the problem in the test or the production site?

If anyone have any insight into this, please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure you are not keeping this column as mandatory in production.

Comment: No, it's not mandatory. I forgot to mention that. The columns and their settings are identical.